# Eclipse RCP PropertyTester never gets called via menu visibleWhen

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'd like to implement a custom propertytester for my custom navigator view pop-up menu. Unfortunately it never actually gets called. Here are the `plugin.xml` parts and the class.

The defined property tester:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
  <propertyTester
        class="com.mytest.MyPropertyTester"
        id="com.mytest.myPropertyTester"
        namespace="com.mytest.myPropertyTester"
        properties="testProperty"
        type="com.mytest.MyPropertyTester">
  </propertyTester>
```

The definition part:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions">
  <definition
        id="org.eclipse.example.testExtension">
     <adapt
           type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
        <test
              property="com.mytest.myPropertyTester.testProperty">
        </test>
     </adapt>
  </definition>
```

The visibleWhen part:

```
<command
           commandId="com.mytest.testcommand"
           label="Test Command"
           style="push">
         <visibleWhen
              checkEnabled="false">
           <with
                 variable="activeMenuSelection">
              <iterate
                    ifEmpty="false"
                    operator="or">
                 <or>
                    <reference
                          definitionId="org.eclipse.example.testExtension">
                    </reference>
                 </or>
              </iterate>
           </with>
        </visibleWhen>
     </command>
```

And the corresponding class:

```
package com.mytest;

import org.eclipse.core.expressions.PropertyTester;

public class MyPropertyTester extends PropertyTester {

public MyPropertyTester() {
    System.out.println("PROPERTY TESTER CONSTRUCTOR");
}

@Override
public boolean test(Object receiver, String property, Object[] args,
        Object expectedValue) {
    System.out.println("PROPERTY TESTER CALLED");
    return true;
}

}
```

Without the "test" used in the org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions part everything works fine.

It seems that not even the constructor of the `MyPropertyTester` class gets called. I haven’t really found any working example regarding this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is your `type` value (`type="com.mytest.MyPropertyTester"`) in your `propertyTester` definition.

The object to be tested must be an instance of the type (or adapt to) before the tester will be called (the help is very vague about this!).

Use `type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.IAdaptable"` which will match most objects or `type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource"` to just match resources.

Comment: @greg-449, in my case, the object was in fact an instance of the type `com.mytest.MyPropertyTester`. And my `<test>` is really within an `<adapt>` of type `com.mytest.MyPropertyTester`! I Still don't see my `PropertyTester` implementation getting called! Any clue why?

Comment: FWIW, I'm checking if the `selection` corresponds to that of a DOM element. The `<test>` additionally checks if the DOM element belongs to a certain namespace and has a specific node name.

Answer (score 9):

I know this question was answered already, but I faced the same problem due to a different reason; so just thought I will put it out here.

In my case, the `org.eclipse.core.expressions` plugin was not activated at the point my `<test>` expression was evaluated, so it was simply skipping the evaluation.

So I had to force the plugin activation using `forcePluginActivation=true`, like:

```
<test 
      property="org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.isSelectedElementARunnableSeleniumTestSuite"
      value="true" 
      forcePluginActivation="true">
</test>
```

Quoting the [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_menus.html#e.test),

> - forcePluginActivation - a flag indicating whether the plug-in
>     contributing the property tester should be loaded if necessary. As
>     such, this flag should be used judiciously, in order to avoid
>     unnecessary plug-in activations. Most clients should avoid setting
>     this flag to true. This flag is only honored if the evaluation context
>     used to evaluate this expression allows plug-in activation. Otherwise
>     the flag is ignored and no plug-in loading takes place.